# How do I link for a post from the static page?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, blogs

I am developing a wordpress theme and I was wondering...

How can I link to a single blog post from a static page?

My idea is to have a home page (static) where I display the cards of the articles in specific ways with slides, grids, etc...

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

**// put this code on function.php**

```
 add_shortcode('custom_post', 'grid_post')
 
 function grid_post(){
   $args = array(  
        'post_type' => 'posts',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => 8, 
    );

    $loop = new WP_Query( $args ); 
        
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 
          ?>
            <a href='<?php the_permalink() ?>'><?php the_title() ?></a>
        <?php
    endwhile;

    wp_reset_postdata(); 
}
```

**then put this code where you want to show**

```
echo do_shortcode(['custom_post'])
```